# Node Multer disconnect: how to release memory

Tags: node.js, multer

I'm using multer for uploading files. In this project I must handle files the size roughly equal to 3Gb.

When I manualy close browser during uploading, I have no any errors in console (using domain in enter point and console.log on error).
I can see the file uploaded on hard disc, but it's not completely uploaded indeed. If I try to delete it manualy, it appears after a few seconds.
If I restart the server, this file's size is slightly increased. Then I can delete it.

I tried to use

```
req.on('close', () => {
  console.log('close!');
  fs.unlink(path, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log('err:');
      console.log(err);
      return;
    }
    console.log(`connection was failed. unfinished uploading file cleaned`);
  });
});
```

In this case I see 'close!' and domain error (not the err) in console. So, I can't delete this file using the node.js tools.

So, how to remove this file from memory?